# Capistrano - how to run a single migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, capistrano

Is there any way to run a single migration through Capistrano?

I know about

```
deploy:migrate
deploy:migrations
```

But is there something like

```
cap staging deploy:migrate:up VERSION=version_number
```

?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just created a gem for this purpose: [capistrano-rails-db](https://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano-rails-db) ([Github](https://github.com/kentaroi/capistrano-rails-db))

For example, you can run a specific migration up as follows:

```
cap staging deploy:db:migrate:up VERSION=version_number
```